# receiveFrom POCO datagram

Tags: sockets, udp, poco, datagram

I want to get a clear explanation of what happens in this function from POCO networking using datagrams under certain conditions.

```
int receiveFrom(void* buffer, int length, SocketAddress& address, int flags = 0);
    /// Receives data from the socket and stores it
    /// in buffer. Up to length bytes are received.
    /// Stores the address of the sender in address.
    ///
    /// Returns the number of bytes received.
```

I am wondering if the buffer I pass to the function is smaller than the datagram will this function read what it can into the buffer and retain the extra data for a subsequent receive from function?

So far I have been passing a buffer that matches the size of the incoming data, but I am unsure of the precise behaviour of this function when;

the size parameter is smaller than the buffer or

The size of the incoming data is larger than the buffer

The size parameter is larger than the incoming data.

If anyone knows these details it would be great to know.

Cheers

Comment: Not working is not a good description of what is going wrong.  What kind of issue are you seeing?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I should go back to check fundamentals to make sure my code is well made. I am missing a response from the device- I had built my code by reworking code from another platform with a differently structured udp library, one where if the buffer fed to the recvfrom function is smaller than the datagram then the remainder of the datagram can be read by the next pass of recvfrom. Obviously without the response my code does not work. Rather than paste whole chunks of more meaningless code I tried to isolate my question to something more focused.

Comment: Edited post to remove why I wanted to know, just to reflect what I want to know- did not realise this would get a downvote.

Answer (score 1):

> the size parameter is smaller than the buffer

It is C like code, the function doesn't know the size of the buffer that is why you have to tell it the size.  Using a size smaller than the buffer means the function will only use the space you tell it about not the full buffer.

> The size of the incoming data is larger than the buffer

When you call read you will get a buffer full of data, the data you didn't read will be returned on the next read.  When you have code that can send messages of different sizes, normally you put a fixed size header on the messages that contains the full message length. The receiver then reads the header and determines how much to read to get the full message.

> The size parameter is larger than the incoming data.

The function tells you how much data it read.  When your buffer is larger than the amount read, the unused portion of the buffer is untouched.